# How to keep only the first character in a sting

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a way to store the first character in a string, I have used substring, but it did not work for me, since I want to keep only the first character in string regradless of the number of characters in the string. 
This is the code I currently have:

```
If RadioButton2.Checked Then

                RichTextBox1.Rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}  " &
                   vbNewLine &
                      "- " & TextBox1.Text.Substring(2) & "," &
                      TextBox2.Text & ", " &
                      "\i " & TextBox5.Text & ". " & "\i0 " &
                      TextBox9.Text & ", " &
                      TextBox10.Text & ". "

            End If
```

I am specifically looking for the first character in the string contained in textbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first character, specify the start index, and count.

```
TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1)
```

Comment: You don't need to count... You said you only want the first character.    TextBox1.Text = "blaa blaa blaa whatever"    Debug.Writeline(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1))    would = "b"

Comment: It worked for me !! thank you a lot . I do appreciate.

Comment: Excellent. However, would also be good practice to check that the TextBoxes actually contain something first.       If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then ..........